# Exporting with SQL Developer and keeping primary Key

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer to access an oracle database. I want to export that table and keep the primary keys generation. 
Since I can´t use SQLloader I can only use "export to sql".

**Here is an example:**

Database1 is the database that contains the data I want to copy to another database (Database2). The next record on Database1 will get the primary key 200.

Database2 should get all the Data from Database1 (including primary keys, foreign key etc etc etc). When I drop the table there and recreate it using the sql that sql developer gave me and create a new record it will get the ID 92 (EXAMPLE !!).

This will certainly lead me into issues.

Is there any way to create the table and make sure it will get the same primary key that it would get if it would run run Database1 ?

Comment: you mean you have a sequence and you do not know how to make it generate higher numbers? Just recreate the sequence anyway.

Comment: I don´t know if I have a sequence - I have a table with a primary key in it. Is there a way to find out the sequence for a primary key ?

Comment: Found the sequence :)

Comment: Good, you're on the track.

Comment: If you export your data using SQL Developer it will create an exact copy of your primary keys in your target schema. You can try creating an export of that table and check the generated script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be in your situation you use sequence and you can find it in one of the triggers at the table. Next should alter sequence like below:

```
 DROP SEQUENCE my_seq;

 CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq
 START WITH 200
 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999
 MINVALUE 1
```

So that way let you to load data. But I think copy PK from one database to another isn't a good idea, because PK sensitive for storage level data, not business data